# Electromagnetic induction with a two-magnet assembly

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, experimental-physics

I performed a bunch of experiments where I let a two-magnet assembly free fall through a vertical solenoid. The magnets are shaped like rings, are identical in size, and are held in place - with a distance d between them - in a plastic capsule like structure such that they repel each other.

I am able to vary d in the capsule and measure peak voltage. After 15 capsule drops for every d, I got the following results.

| d | Voltage (avg. of peak volts) |
| --- | --- |
| 3/8 inch | 29.24 V |
| 15/16 inch | 33.79 V |
| 1 3/8 inch | 36.69 V |
| 2 inch | 35.94 V |
| 2 1/4 inch | 34.21 V |

Could you please help me interpret the results. What is perplexing is that the peak voltage increases before decreasing as I increase d.

Comment: The EMF varies in time as the magnet falls.  What do you call average EMF in your table?

Comment: Sorry, this is peak EMF. Avg. EMF would then be the avg. of all 15 peaks. I just fixed it

Comment: What is the length of the coil?

Comment: 1.5 inch length and 0.37 inch diameter. The coil remains the same throughout the experiment

Answer (score 1):

First assume extreme situations. The second magnet goes through the tube after the first one has left it. You clearly get two voltages. If you reduce the distance, you get overlapping peaks.

You only get the full picture when you measure the power produced by the falling magnets. (By the way, I find it strange to call the measured voltage the EMF).

Some possible cases:

- The power (summarised over the fall time) is constant for all distances d. The experiment is finished.
- The harvestable output power is not a constant value for different d. The possible reason is electrical power losses due to the overlapping induction processes of two magnetic sources.

Comment: I believe constructive interference is how I get more volts as d decreases. But this does not explain the decrease in volts after 36.69V. What do you think is happening. The current hovers around 1A pretty consistently for all experiments